# Command '['dot', '-Tpng']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, graphviz

I've been trying execute a code in Jupyter notebook to make a random forest graphic using graphviz. I install graphviz with Anaconda promt and I already configura the system variables.

The exactly error is:

**CalledProcessError: Command '['dot', '-Tpng']' returned non-zero exit status 1. [stderr: b'Format: "png" not recognized. Use one of:\r\n']**

My code is:

```
graph = Source(tree.export_graphviz(num_tree,
                                    out_file=None,
                                    feature_names=X_train.columns,
                                    class_names=['0', '1'],
                                    filled = True))

display(Image(data=graph.pipe(format='png')))
```

hope you will help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Format: "svg" not recognized. Use one of:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769161/error-format-svg-not-recognized-use-one-of)

Comment: Yes!!! thanks a lot!! I  solved it by installing version 2.38 instead of 2.44!